# Can I override the standard (Global) Search Results page?

Tags: global-search

I am working with a mobile publisher app and a group of users (1 profile) that need to be altogether blocked from seeing Activity records (Task and Event). SF Support indicated that there might be a way to override the standard Search Results page with a custom Lightning Component, but wasn't able to provide any kind of documentation about the capability. I've searched for anything about this capability, but can't find anything either.

This is not for a Community. This is for a mobile publisher app that's built on a Lightning App. The org also has Einstein Search enabled, which I suspect might change what I'm able to do.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the gotcha that stops you simply removing that profile's access to Tasks and Events via permissions?

Comment: I've already removed the profile's ability to edit events/tasks, and I've hidden the respective tabs, as well. There is a permission called `Access Activities`, but it's only editable for Community-based profiles (per SF Support Tier 3).